# Which data structure may produce an overflow error even though the current number of elements in it is lower than its size

Tags: arrays, queue

This question was in the SHL assesment that I gave a few days back. The options for the question are:

Options:

a) A queue implemented in a linear array
b) A queue implemented in circularly connected array
c) A stack implemented in a linear array
d) None of the above

According to me answer should be option B i.e. A queue implemented in circularly connected array.

Because, In a circularly connected array-based queue, even though the current number of elements in the queue may be lower than its size, it's possible to encounter an overflow error. This can happen when the front and rear pointers of the queue wrap around the end of the array and meet each other, indicating that the queue is full, even if there are still available empty spaces in the array. This condition can occur due to the circular nature of the queue, where the rear pointer wraps around to the beginning of the array when it reaches the end.

But, after the result came out I found out that option A i.e. A queue implemented in a linear array.

i am not sure if the answer provided by SHL is correct.

Comment: This is not related to Digital Signature Algorithm (`dsa`). Tag removed.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning you gave, is actually the reason why the overflow would occur with a *linear* array.

You write:

> ...when the front and rear pointers of the queue wrap around the end of the array and meet each other

The front and the rear pointers move in the same direction in the circular array (let's say clockwise), so the only time they can meet is when the queue is full; there just is no other way for them to meet (excluding the case where the queue is empty -- all depending on how it is implemented -- but that is not a case of overflow). By definition the circular distance between the rear and the front, is the size of the queue. When front and rear would meet, it would represent a full circle, i.e. the queue is full.

However, with a linear array, both pointers also move in one direction, i.e. forward. An overflow occurs when the furthest pointer walks beyond the length of the array, but this says nothing about where the other pointer currently is at, and thus nothing about the size of the queue. By consequence, you can easily get an overflow with a linear array.

#### Example

Let's illustrate this with an example. First let's picture both data structures, each with an array of size 4, and after already the values 10, 20 and 30 were enqueued in that order. I will assume that the rear side is where items are *enqueued*, and the front side is where items are *dequeued*. You can of course name them in the opposite sense... it doesn't matter.

Both the linear array and circular array implementations will look like this (we could swap the :

```
    Linear Array                 Circular Array
┌────┬────┬────┬────┐         ┌────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ 10 │ 20 │ 30 │ -- │         │ 10 │ 20 │ 30 │ -- │ 
└────┴────┴────┴────┘         └────┴────┴────┴────┘
  ↑         ↑                   ↑         ↑
front      rear               front      rear
```

Now let's dequeue a value from the queue, which is value 10. The effect is still the same:

```
    Linear Array                 Circular Array
┌────┬────┬────┬────┐         ┌────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ 10 │ 20 │ 30 │ -- │         │ 10 │ 20 │ 30 │ -- │ 
└────┴────┴────┴────┘         └────┴────┴────┴────┘
       ↑    ↑                        ↑    ↑
     front rear                    front rear
```

When we enqueue the value 40, we're still OK:

```
    Linear Array                 Circular Array
┌────┬────┬────┬────┐         ┌────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ 10 │ 20 │ 30 │ 40 │         │ 10 │ 20 │ 30 │ 40 │ 
└────┴────┴────┴────┘         └────┴────┴────┴────┘
       ↑         ↑                   ↑         ↑
     front      rear               front      rear
```

Let's dequeue a value, which is 40. No problems yet:

```
    Linear Array                 Circular Array
┌────┬────┬────┬────┐         ┌────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ 10 │ 20 │ 30 │ 40 │         │ 10 │ 20 │ 30 │ 40 │ 
└────┴────┴────┴────┘         └────┴────┴────┴────┘
            ↑    ↑                        ↑    ↑
          front rear                    front rear
```

But now we get to the situation that is critical. We want to enqueue the value 50:

```
    Linear Array                 Circular Array
┌────┬────┬────┬────┐         ┌────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ 10 │ 20 │ 30 │ 40 │ ?       │ 50 │ 20 │ 30 │ 40 │ 
└────┴────┴────┴────┘         └────┴────┴────┴────┘
            ↑         ↑         ↑         ↑
          front      rear      rear     front
```

The first implementation gets into an overflow situation: `rear` is now out of range, and the value 50 cannot be stored. Yet the actual size of the queue would have been 3 (if it had worked without overflow), while the data structure has size 4.

The circular array doesn't have this issue: the rear pointer wraps around, and as it hasn't met the front pointer, the enqueue operation can be completed without problems. There are now 3 items in a data structure with size 4.

The only way that the rear pointer can catch up with the front pointer and become equal with it, is when the queue has four items, and we want to add a fifth.

As a side note: it should be understood that the circular implementation would need a special state to indicate that the queue is empty, otherwise a full queue and empty queue could not be distinguished. This could for instance be achieved by setting the front/rear pointers to null when the queue is/becomes empty.